# Python format time string to datetime object

Tags: python, string, datetime

I'm trying to format the time string "2016-01-01 00:00:00" to a datetime object. I tried the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
d = datetime.strptime(a,'%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But I got the error message saying:

```
ValueError: time data '2016-01-01 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'
```

What's wrong with my code?
Thank you all for helping me!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-` hyphens are missing in your format string:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'

#                Hyphens here  v  v       
>>> d = datetime.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your format string is wrong. This works:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
d = datetime.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```